How can i get outlook emails using az cli?
I am trying to get outlook emails using az cli
 $userEmail = "user@example.com"
 $folderName = "Inbox" # Specify the folder name you want to retrieve emails from
 $outputFile = "emails.xlsx" # Specify the Excel file where you want to store the emails

 $outlookMessages = Get-AzOutlookMessage -MailboxEmailAddress $userEmail -FolderName $folderName

 $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
 $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
  $sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)

It gives and error that the term 'Get-MgAuthenticationToken' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.
Which module do i need to install for this or is there an easier way ?

Get-AzOutlookMessage is not a satandard PS Cmdlet.  Where did you get the code?  You forgot to copy the cmdlet Get-MgAuthenticationToken

From admin elevated PowerShell run Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Authentication to install the Microsoft Graph PowerShell Authentication Module.
The PowerShell example here requires passing in the M365 tenant id, the Enterprise app's client id and client secret to a function to get the token for Graph authentication.
This method requires an M365 App Registration configured with Mail.Read and you should also take the advice and "configure an application access policy to limit app access to specific mailboxes and not to all the mailboxes in the organization."
$M365ClientId = "abc";
$M365ClientSecret = "xyz";
$tenantId = "mnopqrstuz";
$folderName = "Inbox";
$mailboxUserId = "mailbox@domain.com";

Function Get-M365AccessToken (){
    $clientId = $args[0];     ### Pass in client id
    $clientSecret = $args[1]; ### Pass in client secret "value"
    $TenantId = $args[2];     ### Pass in tenantid
    
    Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Authentication
    
    $body = @{
        grant_type = "client_credentials";
        client_id = $clientId;
        client_secret = $clientSecret;
        scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
    }
    
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $body
    $accessToken = $response.access_token
    Return $accessToken; 
    };

$AccessToken = Get-M365AccessToken $M365ClientId $M365ClientSecret $tenantId;

Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Authentication;
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $accessToken;

$messages = Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage -UserId $mailboxUserId -MailFolderId $folderName -Top 100;
$messages;


This gives an error:  Cannot bind parameter 'AccessToken'  Cannot convert the $accesstoken  value of type  "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString". ?

It gives that error when it tries to run Connect-MgGraph $AccessToken ?

Now it says the term Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage  is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet ?

I have registerd an app with the permission , but how do you give permission to the email ? do you need to go to azure entra id and access control ?

I have fixed the token issue , but now it says , Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. Is there a module I need to install ?

@Stacey Try Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Mail and see if that does it. Of course follow that with Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Mail too.

yes i worked that out , thanks . But now it just gives    Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage : One or more errors occurred.  CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage_List], AggregateException    thats it

I have use the user id for $mailboxUserId and the folder id for $folderid  not the actual textual names ?

The folder is a different one than Inbox  and i have set it to that . The folder is called TestFolderA ?

Weird, I use account@domain.com and 'foldername' and it works in my scripts that way without any special id numbers.

Only have done this with SentItems and Inbox though so I have not tried subfolders and different folders and such. There could be a gotcha there!

I just tried the Inbox same error ?

I have directly put the values in the Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage no difference . Are you able to please modify the code above , thankyou ?

what do you mean Expose an API , sorry am relatively new to all of this trying to learn it ?

I have checked the app and yes it has Mail.Read. No nothing has worked up to that point.  But according to the documentaion , on Microsoft it says the MailFolder is an id and so is UserId ?

even using the unique identifier for both user and folder doesnt seem to work , same error ?

I have added a scope in Expose API, it is Mail.Read ?

I just add the scope with a name like username.read.mail or jsmith.read.mailfolder, and then ensure it is enabled and set to admins only. Another way with com PowerShell using Outlook M365 while it is up and running, I have used this but only for the folder inbox though: https://imgur.com/gHKKwEz

ok will try ... and let you know

it is in the enterprise app , have tested no difference  and under app registration , does the account need to be there , if so under where do i put it

I am looking at using Invoke-RestMethod , this seems to get the email content , i have seen examples , what do you think ?

I think i have got it .. you need to install and import the module , Microsoft.Graph, I am checking that

Now if i do   $messages = (Get-MgUserMailFolderMessage -UserId $mailboxUserId -MailFolderId $folderName -Top 100) | ConvertTo-Json  , i get a json result. How can i get each individual property in the Body  ?

I can now get body , content, via just using $messages.Body etc. But the body is very long and it just displays ... (3 dots) . How can i expand it and the other properties aswell ?

I always check with $messages | Select * sort of deal to see properties.

@Stacey Getting the $messages variable built per the solution without the pipe over to ConvertTo-Json I wrote about, you can then $messages | Select * to see all properties. Usually you can $messages.propertyname where .<propertyname> is for the field in the select statements which you want to expand. Not literally "propertyname" but the 'name of the property' as listed from | Select * from the variable as I put in the logic examples. Try to pipe to FL vs FT too so $messages.Body | FL vs $messages.Body | FT output. Feel free to delete your old comments since you got it!
